# Destination host unreachable

Tags: unix, networking, routes

I have 3 VMs with Ubuntu 12.10: m1, m2 and m3. 
Here are their IPs

```
m1 = 192.168.1.1
m2 = 192.168.2.1
m3 = 192.168.3.1
```

When I try to ping between them, I get a destination host unreachable. 
If I set them to 192.168.1.X, then the ping works fine, so the VM setup is working fine. The issue is when I put them in a different 192.168.X ip.

What's the ideal setup for all 3 machines to be able to ping each other?

Comment: Change netmask to something a bit wider than /24, or just slap 255.255.0.0 in there.  But that should be considered a stopgap measure, not really a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a normal netmask of 255.255.255.0, that means that they are on different subnets. You need to set up some way of routing between them. I don't know what virtualization software you're using, but the 2 most common ones (VMWare and Virtualbox) both have support for configuring and modifying virtual networks.

You will have to look for the network settings config options.

EDIT: Depending on what you're trying to do, dennis' answer may be easier.

Answer (score 2):

Change the subnet mask accordingly: in your case, `255.255.0.0`